# Structuring Docker for building a monolithic app

Tags: docker, dockerfile

We have a monolithic build process for a [ROS-based application](http://wiki.ros.org), and want to employ Docker to package it up so we can more easily test and deploy.

My current thinking is that I build an image that contains all the dependencies, then use `ENTRYPOINT` and suitable `--mount` commands to do our final `cmake` and build the local source into a container.

However, there is one major design issue I haven't worked out a solution to or best practice for yet. First, I have obtained the [OpenCV+CUDA](https://github.com/loitho/docker-opencv-cuda) image and a suitable [ROS image](https://hub.docker.com/_/ros/), so I need to combine both into a new container, but the `FROM` command doesn't seem to suffice. For instance, OpenCV has been installed with `make install`, and CUDA has been through whatever `apt-get` processing is necessary, so I cannot just `COPY` over the files `--from` one after switching to the second. Practically, when I currently try to build `cmake` complains about `CUDA_TOOLKIT_ROOT_DIR` being missing, and if I hack that there will no doubt be another similar error a few more lines into the `makefile`.

How do people get around "multiple image inheritance" (for lack of a better word)? Should I be, say, just doing `apt get cuda8` in my final `Dockerfile` instead of relying on `FROM docker-opencv-cuda` to indirectly provide an environment? That, though has the problem of somehow ensuring my CUDA versions are in sync between images.